# How can I use MongoDB as data source for Spark Streaming? Can I send data from MongoDB to Apache Streaming via Kafka?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, data-stream

I stored time-series sensor data in MongoDB and I want to use MongoDB data in Spark Streaming. I tried to connect Apache Kafka but I couldn't find anything.

So, can I send data from MongoDB to Spark Streaming via Kafka or other stream tools? Is it possible? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: check out https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-mongodb